# Convergence radius $\beta$=sup{|$\lambda$|: $\lambda$ $\in$ $\Bbb K$ , $(\sum_{k=0}^n c_k \lambda^k)_n$ bounded )

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let be (E, $\Vert .\Vert$) a $\Bbb K$-banach space , $(c_k)_k$ a sequence in E , $\beta$ the convergence radius 
of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \lambda^k$ . In my script is $\beta$ defined by Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Prove: 
$\beta$=sup{|$\lambda$|: $\lambda$ $\in$ $\Bbb K$ , $(\sum_{k=0}^n c_k \lambda^k)_n$ bounded in E }=:s .

My thoughts:

To show
1)  s$\le$ $\beta$
2)  $\beta$ $\le$ s .

To 1) : Let $a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k \lambda^k$, M:={$\lambda$ $\in$$\Bbb K$ :$(a_n)_n$ bounded} , $S_n$:=$\sum_{k=0}^n \Vert c_k \lambda^k \Vert $. If I can show |$\lambda$|$\le$$\beta$ ,$\forall$ $\lambda$ $\in$M,then I'm done.
Assume: $\exists$ $\lambda$ $\in$M with |$\lambda$|>$\beta$. 
Because $\beta$ is convergence radius , for C>0 there is N $\in \Bbb N$ with
$S_n>C ,\forall n\ge N$ .
To show: $\lambda \notin M$ . That means t.s: $(a_n)_n$ is unbounded.
T.s: For $C>0, \exists n \in \Bbb N$ with $\Vert a_n \Vert>C$. (*)

Do you know, how can you show (*) ?
Or, do you have another suggestion, how  can be solved the task ?